# What are the options of collapsable list widgets in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I need to have some lists collapse by their topics in my project and am wondering if I'll need to implement this from zero or rather use a component from flutter. Does this component exist?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: _collapse by their topic_ ??

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I want it to look like an [accordion](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_collapse.asp), in which the sections' contents are ListViews

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The Flutter Gallery has two examples that may be relevant for your accordion-like lists.

[Expansion Panel Demo](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/flutter_gallery/lib/demo/material/expansion_panels_demo.dart) & [Two-level List Demo](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/flutter_gallery/lib/demo/material/two_level_list_demo.dart)

The Expansion Panel demo is probably what you want. If so, take a look at how the demo leverages [ExpansionPanel](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/expansion_panel.dart) and uses a `headerBuilder` and `body`. You can extends this to make the header and bodies as complex as you need. The Gallery demo adds a [DemoItem](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/flutter_gallery/lib/demo/material/expansion_panels_demo.dart#L144-L173) helper class. You can use this pattern or come up with your own design.

Here is a snippet that shows the demo using `ExpansionPanelList` by passing a callback and the list of `DemoItem`s:

```
        child: new ExpansionPanelList(
          expansionCallback: (int index, bool isExpanded) {
            setState(() {
              _demoItems[index].isExpanded = !isExpanded;
            });
          },
          children: _demoItems.map((DemoItem<dynamic> item) {
            return new ExpansionPanel(
              isExpanded: item.isExpanded,
              headerBuilder: item.headerBuilder,
              body: item.build()
            );
          }).toList()
        ),
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, two-level lists are deprecated as of now, so I'll give `ExpansionPanel` a try!

Comment: @JotaRenan, where did you notice it was deprecated? I didn't see anything in the docs here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/expansion_tile.dart

Comment: VScode flags it: `'TwoLevelList' is deprecated and shouldn't be used.`

Comment: Ah! @JotaRenan, yes TwoLevelList is deprecated but the demo uses ExpansionTile.

Here is a link to the Demo with ExpansionTile using ListTiles: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/flutter_gallery/lib/demo/material/two_level_list_demo.dart#L17-L27

Here is the old reference to DEPRECATED: TwoLevelList https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/0259be90b8cc6b66e47a319118560aaf3e81d207/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/two_level_list.dart#L42-L43